# Use custom color AND custom label from dataframe columns in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like ggplot to take the color and label aesthetics from the dataframe that's being plotted.  I understand you can use `scale_colour_identity()` to take color from the data.frame (the `col` column below) but I'm not sure how to get it to read custom labels too (the `lab` column below).

Note: I appreciate you can do these things by hard-coding the labels and colours the script (the bunch of `manual` commands in ggplot).  However, I want to avoid hard-coding these things in the R script (which seems like bad coding practice to me) because it makes it more difficult for me to then use the same plotting metadata in a Python script (or another R script), for instance.  I appreciate you could also put colours in an R script and source() them but then the same issue arises in trying to use consistent colours in Python plots.

```
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

# Define test dataset
n_trt <- 3
n_samples <- 5
cols <- c("#F2762E", "#F2AB27", "#4F8C11")

df <- data.frame(
    trt = rep(LETTERS[1:n_trt], each = n_samples),
    response_x = rep(rnorm(n_trt), each = n_samples) + runif(n_trt*n_samples),
    response_y = rep(rnorm(n_trt), each = n_samples) + runif(n_trt*n_samples),
    col = rep(cols, each = n_samples),
    lab = rep(paste0(LETTERS[1:n_trt], letters[1:n_trt]), each = n_samples))

#> print(head(df))
#  trt response_x response_y     col lab
#1   A  2.1075468 -0.1803944 #F2762E  Aa
#2   A  1.5056250 -0.6391629 #F2762E  Aa
#3   A  2.0279507 -0.2501283 #F2762E  Aa
#4   A  2.0760232 -0.3485370 #F2762E  Aa
#5   A  1.8287002 -0.2750774 #F2762E  Aa
#6   B  0.1544141  2.0014811 #F2AB27  Bb

# Plotting routine
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = response_x, y = response_y, 
        color = col, labels = lab, group = lab)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
    scale_colour_identity(guide = "legend", aes(labels = lab)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position = "top")

ggsave("test.png", p, width = 6, height = 4)
```

[image: test.png]

Answer (score 2):

One can use `unique()` with the `_manual_` suite of functions but this relies on ordering behaviour of `unique()` being consistent so not ideal.

```
df$col <- as.character(df$col)
df$lab <- as.character(df$lab)

# Plotting routine
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = response_x, y = response_y, group = lab)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = lab), size = 2.5) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_color_manual(name = "", values = unique(df$col), labels = unique(df$lab)) + 
    theme(legend.position = "top")

ggsave("test.png", p, width = 6, height = 4)
```

[image: test.png]

Comment: you basically found the way to do this. Mind you that you can supply the `values` and `labels` that you want to control with `_manual`. Thus, you can set the values/labels via a vector. Obviously this is done by hand and a function like unique() will not help. But you could work with factors, or order the vector elements in a different manner. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making use of `unique()` you could pass your desired colors and labels as a named vector to `scale_color_manual` which ensures that colors are assigned to the right categories. As you have colors and labels inside a dataframe your could make  use of `dplyr::distinct` and `tibble::deframe` to make named vectors like so:

```r
require(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

cols <- dplyr::distinct(df, trt, col) %>% tibble::deframe()
cols
#>         A         B         C 
#> "#F2762E" "#F2AB27" "#4F8C11"
labs <- dplyr::distinct(df, trt, lab) %>% tibble::deframe()
labs
#>    A    B    C 
#> "Aa" "Bb" "Cc"

# Plotting routine
ggplot(df, aes(x = response_x, y = response_y, color = trt)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols, labels = labs) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Control your labels with a separate layer.
To ensure the labels do not overlap with your points, you can offset them with nudge_x or nudge_y.

If you run into issues with overlapping labels, read up on geom_text_repel().

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = response_x, y = response_y, 
                    color = col, labels = lab, group = lab)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = lab), nudge_x = 0.2) +
    scale_colour_identity(guide = "legend", aes(labels = lab)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position = "top")
p
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was looking for a general solution where they're labelled in the legend (like the test.png in the question).  Adding labels in the figure isn't applicable across other geom's (like lines) or in non-trivial datasets that have 100s of points.

Comment: no prob @p-robot. You spotted the solution to your problem which was not evident from your question. Great.